# Get day from DateTime using C#

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek

Silly question. Given a date in a datetime and I know it's tuesday for instance how do i know its tue=2 and mon=1 etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking for the [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property.
Then, as Dan suggests in the comment below, just look at the integer value of the enum to get the day as integer:

```
int d = (int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
```

Comment: Sorry i posted the wrong question.Apologies.
Given that I know it's thursday how do I map to a number EG 
monday=1
tue=2 etc..
so given the date I need to know that is monday and =1 
how do i do that?

Comment: How do you know Monday == 1?  By looking at the enum!

Comment: @devnet maybe you should follow the link and read. The clear example shows the usage and output. ("The day of the week for {0:d} is {1}.", dt, dt.DayOfWeek) gives The day of the week for 5/1/2003 is Thursday.

Comment: @devnet247: Are you also looking for this: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to find out the name of the day, you can do this as follows:

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek

Response.Write(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() will give name of day

Answer (score 3):

DayOfWeek is an Enum. To get the integer instead of the string representation you can cast it

```
int i = (int)d.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes DateTime has DayOfWeek() method.

Comment: It is not a method, it is a property and can be accessed like the other answers.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
int day = (int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
string dayoftheweek;
```

In the public partial class Form :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form class
```

(For a c# winforms application)

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime (txtMaxDate.Value); /*Store date in dt */
int day = dt.Day; /*Get date as (01-01-2019 then it will give 01 as day)*/
```

Comment: please explain why this snippet solves the problem, and look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

label3.Text = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();

Answer (score -1):

DayOfWeek today = new DateTime().DayOfWeek;

Console.WriteLine(today);