# How to get just the days number as an int from datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm looking for a way to assign the current day to an `int`.

For example today is the 10th of February so I would like to assign the int 10 to a variable.

Comment: how about using [`Day`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property?

Comment: int Result = DateTime.Now.Day;

Comment: The date in which time zone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get day from DateTime using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988406/get-day-from-datetime-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Joker I don't think this is a duplicate. Your link asks _day number of week_ but this question asks _day number of month_.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.Day` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the number of day as an `Int32`.

```
int dayNumber = DateTime.Now.Day;
```

Remember, this property *always* returns day number in [Gregorian Calender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) of your `DateTime` *even* your `DateTime` is constructed with different calender. If you have a `DateTime` with *different* calender, you can use [`Calendar.GetDayOfMonth` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) to get it's calender day number.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
int dt = DateTime.Today.Day;
```